# Windows 10 black screen boot alongside Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, dualboot

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04 (I've already installed Ubuntu).
I have two disks, a SSD (the main disk with the OS) and a HDD (where some folders such as /var and /home are located).

I want to run Windows 10 in the HDD, so I've formated as NTFS a 250GB size primary partition.

The problem comes when I boot from the USB because my screen turns black with a static cursor in the beginnig. I couldn't even install Windows.

*The USB is properly working since I tried booting it on a laptop.*

Do you think that might be a graphic card problem? Or what should I try?

> *The PC:*
> AMD Ryzen 5 3600
> Gigabyte Aorus B450 M
> GTX 1050

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are you getting black screen with a static cursor in the beginning while booting windows or Ubuntu? If it is windows bootable USB then try recreate it using Rufus : https://rufus.ie/ ; Also make sure CSM mode is off in BIOS

Comment: Thanks @Madhubala! Yes, it is the windows booteable... I created with UNetbootin because I don't have any windows running for downloading Rufus. All in all, the USB seems to be working because I've tried with a laptop and it boots. The CSM mode is already off in BIOS... :/

Comment: If you are on linux use Woeusb , https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB

Comment: Yes! The windows installer has appeared! Now another problem comes... It sais that the partition that I want to use is not valid due to my partition table. I'm using MRB table in the PC and the Windows seems to be impossible to install there. It needs GPT. What can i do @Madhubala?

Comment: It depends what you want to do - 1)want gpt - then convert whole disk to gpt 2)want mbr - enable CSM mode in bios and everything will work 3)want hybrid mbr(https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) ; for converting disk to gpt without formatting - use gdisk in linux ;added an answer to your original question ; feel free to accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-creating win USB -

If you have access to another windows PC, use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)

If you are on linux use [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB)

Also turn off CSM mode in bios if you are installing it on Gpt disk